# How to see the SQL query for my lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
    public static IList<EmployeeObject> GetAllEmployee()
    {
        IList<EmployeeObject> emps = new List<EmployeeObject>();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            //....
            using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                  //...add
                }
            }
         }
       return emps.ToList();
     }


public static IQueryable<EmployeeObject> QueryableSQL()
{
    IQueryable<EmployeeObject> queryable = EmployeeRepository.GetAllEmployee(); 
}
```

requirement to cross check the Lambda expression query is correct or not. It means how the lambda expression execute against, I'm not using Entity framework, I have searched on the web and I did not find any blog that related to what I'm looking for.
Any help SQL Profiler? or ObjectQuery? anything that shows me what sql is generating.

```
var query = QueryableSQL().Where(employee => 
    employee.Interests.Any(interest => interest.Name ==  "Chess"));
```

Comment: There is no SQL generated. As LINQ operated with objects in memory and does not query database at all.

Comment: i hear you so what should be my approach in order to achieve what i wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>If you are using LINQ to SQL, you can do the following</del>:

1. Actually the easyest thing you can do is look at the `ToString` method of the `IQueryable`:

   ```
   IQueryable<Employee> query = ...; //your query
   var querySql = query.ToString();
   ```
2. You can use the `Log` property of the Linq `DataContext`:

   ```
   using (var dc = new TestDataContext()) //your DataContext
   {
     dc.Log = Console.Out; //it's of TextWriter type, use any suitable
     IQueryable<Employee> query = ...; //your query

     //execute the query, as it'll output the query to the Log only after it's
     //really executed on the database
     foreach (var s in query)
     {
         //...
     }
   }
   ```

---

<del>In EF you could use `ObjectQuery`'s `ToTraceString` method:</del>

```
using (var dc = new TestEntities())
{
    var query = ...;// your query
    var oquery = query as System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery;
    Console.WriteLine(oquery.ToTraceString());
}
```

<del>Or use Visual Studio Intelli Trace...for more info, read: [Profiling Database Activity in the Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx)</del>

---

As now one can see, it's just LINQ to objects...So LINQ does not query database at all. It operates with objects in memory. Well, Visual Studio lacks any query analyzer for LINQ. You may try using LINQPad to test your LINQ queries:
[www.linqpad.net/](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: when I do query.ToString  of the IQuerable I get this: 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EmployeeObject]'

Comment: I'm not using EntityFramework as mentioned in my post. i do not have any datacontext

Comment: What does `QueryableSQL` return? It's probably a `List<T>` already..it means it's already in the memory of your program and the lambda you want to analyze is not executed over the database, but over the objects in memory

Comment: It's appliable to LINQ2SQL

Comment: QueryableSQL should return `IQueryable<T>`...if it returns `List<T>`, it means that you've already queried the database, and all further manipulations over the resulted data are executed in the programm memory, not in over the database.

Comment: i updated my question it does return IQuerable<EmployeeObject>, please see the post

Comment: What does `GetAllEmployee` return? As `QueryableSQL` returns the result of `GetAllEmployee` casted to `IQueryable<EmployeeObject>`...

Comment: At least try using the context's `Log` property and you'll see the query, which is in fact executed over the database.

Comment: so here is what i'm doing, first i am loading all my data from my table around 200 rows and then i'm calling `QueryableSQL` with `where clause` make sense? so in other-words I'm filtering out once i load my data

Comment: If you load your rows in a table and try to apply that `Where` on them, then you do not query the database for that, as the rows are already loaded. On the contrary, if you do not use those rows, but try to do another query to the database with the same base method, which returns those 200 rows, and that method does not return `IQueryable<T>`, then again your database is queried those 200 rows and then these rows are filtered with `Where` in memory

Comment: i see what you are saying... so what should be my approach do i need to change the way i have coded?

Comment: To execute that filter over the database you must apply the filter to the query before the rows are loaded. Otherwise there is no sql query to show, as the operation is done in memory over, say, a collection of objects. It's already not LINQ2SQL, but LINQ to Objects working...

Comment: Do you need those 200 rows for anything really? Probably you should change your `GetAllEmployee` to return `IQueryable` instead of a `List<T>`...This would let you query only the filtered data from the database. You never showed the code of that method, could you?

Comment: Or if you do need to apply the filter over the loaded rows, then I do not know the way to see, how the lambda will manipulate the objects in memory, as there is not SQL in that way...

Comment: i updated my question again past the code that i am using for `GetAllEmployee `

Comment: There is no SQL generated. As LINQ operates with objects in memory and does not query database at all.

Comment: i hear you so what should be my approach in order to achieve what i wanted?

Comment: Use LINQPad...[LINQPad - Query Analyzer for LINQ queries](http://www.jasondeoliveira.com/2008/08/tool-linqpad-good-query-analyser-for.html)

Comment: its a very small project don't want to bother using EF